# mule - how to map components in xml to backing source code

Tags: mule

Mule has many endpoints, components, etc. for example like http:rest-service-component.  How do I know what source component that is so I can try to figure out how to create a custom transformer or something.

That is the higher level question that helps me now and in the future.  The lower level one is that I have a REST endpoint and I am trying to map the payload of that incoming to put it in the payload of the rest-service-component request and then need to get info in the body of the response to set the status code of the response on my inbound endpoint.  I figure I will just use custom transformers.

sidenote:

All of this programming in xml is just wrong(mule is wrong)...if they want dynamic, just use groovy and keep deploying the new groovy script(which is not the way I would go but better than mule as I could actually debug it with a debugger).  They even have choice statements(ie. if...else if...else if) in xml AND inheritance in xml....it's like re-inventing OO in xml.....who dreamed of this stuff.  Of course the biggest issue is I asked around and everyone I talked to says it is 3-5 times less productive to use mule compared to java...oh joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the namespace handler of the module/transport you're interested in finding what class is behind what XML element.

For example, for the HTTP transport look into: http://svn.codehaus.org/mule/tags/mule-3.2.1/transports/http/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/http/config/HttpNamespaceHandler.java

PS. If Mule makes you less productive, why do you use it in the first place? Pick the tools that best fit your needs.

Comment: It was decided by architects on that team that won't budge.  I tried my best but I guess there was a whole argument before I got here and started consulting.(this along with using spring batch for real-time!).  THANKS for the info!